# Nant <csc> build exe System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, nant

I successfully build several projects using `< csc target="exe">`.  However, when I try to run the generated exe, I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Common.Logging, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Common.Logging, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af0
8829b84f0328e'
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory..cctor()
```

It appears that Nant references the dll's while building but does not copy the dependencies into the outputdir resulting in the above runtime exception.  Is there a way to instruct NAnt to copy dependencies automatically?  It's tedious to have to run the exe multiple times to figure out what dependencies are needed and < copy> them into the outputdir one by one.

Comment: As Microsoft MSBuild and Novell XBuild are there, NAnt becomes an obsolete tool.

Comment: No, we are trying to move away from depending on Visual Studio or MSBuild or for that matter any project files that are not essential.

Answer (score 1):

This will add the reference to the project

```
<references basedir="References">
    <include name="Common.Logging.dll" />
</references>
```

This can be used to copy the DLL to the output directory. You could also use a wildcard to include all dll's.

```
<copy todir="${build.dir}">
    <fileset basedir="bin">
        <include name="Common.Logging.dll" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: That instructs NAnt to reference the dll while building, which I'm already doing.  It does not instruct NAnt to copy the dll into outputdir.

Comment: Yes I know < copy> copies the dll's.  If you read the exception I got, you'd notice I'm getting a runtime exception on Common.Logging, which is referenced by Quartz.  To compile, I only need to reference quartz.dll but during runtime, I got the exception because of the implicit dependencies.  It's tedious to figure out implicit dependencies and < copy> them as the exceptions arise.

Comment: I do not know of a way to do this with NAnt.

Answer (score 0):

tedious it is then.  `<copy> <copy> <copy>`